How to make validator online, if it goes offline
I have a solo chain running using BABE consensus. It has 4 validators. I tried to set session keys of one validator by rotating keys. When new session started, it went offline. I am not sure if I made any mistake. Now block production is very slow.
Is there any way to make validator online back? How can we speed up block production?

When a new session start, it takes the queued keys as the new session keys. And update the queued keys.

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/de6733baedf5406c37393c20912536600d3ef6fa/substrate/frame/session/src/lib.rs#L642

When you set a new session keys, the keys go into the next keys.

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/de6733baedf5406c37393c20912536600d3ef6fa/substrate/frame/session/src/lib.rs#L516

So, it requires one session to convert next keys -> queued keys and then another session to transform queued keys -> session keys.
I believe you just need to wait for one more session.
